# Use field from repeater on another pages ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have ACF custom block with repeater, but now I need to take the field value from this repeater to display on another page. I have such a function to display fields from other blocks where there is no repeater, but how can I fix it so that I can also display fields from the repeater?

```
function get_field_from_block( $selector, $post_id, $block_name ) {
    if ( ! has_blocks( $post_id ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $post_blocks = parse_blocks( get_the_content( '', false, $post_id ) );

    foreach ( $post_blocks as $block ) {
        if ( isset( $block['blockName'] ) && $block_name == $block['blockName'] ) {

            if ( isset( $block['attrs']['data'][$selector] ) ) {
                return $block['attrs']['data'][$selector];
            } else {
                break;
            }

        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

and then I use it in code like this:

```
$ticker = get_field_from_block('coin_ban_ticker', $post->ID, 'acf/coin-banner');
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same need and it took ACF support's help to figure it out.

You can replace the innermost `if` with:

```
acf_setup_meta( $block['attrs']['data'], acf_get_block_id( $block['attrs']['data'] ), true );

return get_field( $selector );
```